# RStudio Working Directory Error

Tags: r, rstudio

**Updated** question with more details:

I am not able to open my R workspace, and getting the following error (in base R, RStudio simply shows the first line of error and then freezes):

```
Error: value of 'SET_ATTRIB' must be a pairlist or NULL, not a 'list'
During startup - Warning message:
unable to restore saved data in C:\R_Library\A\.RData
```

Other R Workspaces are loading so definitely it is a corrupt `.RData` file issue. The R Workspace is half a GB in size. I am working on a Windows machine (64-bit) with R version 3.1.2.

My `R` was running slow, and I decided to save my Workspace and relaod the image. That's when the error message started. It could be due to large data in the environment, but I have handled more data before without any issues.

There is no information available on how to fix this issue. I have some unsaved code in the directory, which is the bare minimum I would want to recover. Any advice will be useful.

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-Crash-on-start-up-of-R-Ubuntu-and-Wine-within-Ubuntu-td844985.html

Comment: Saw that, but I don't follow the debug options suggested. I am able to open other directories. So the issue is with the current `.RData` file I am trying to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the file .RData in your R working directory. Start R, and run

```
load("whatever you renamed .RData to").
```

If this still does not work, try clicking on your renamed R project file. It should open your workspace with an empty environment.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Strangely `load` gave the same error, but double-clicking the R project file opened the workspace with an empty environment. Please update your answer with this and I will accept it.

Comment: Updated my answer - tx! Happy something worked out for you.